# Android notification of screen off/on

Tags: android

I'm looking to see if there's a system notification I can listen for to see when the screen turns off/on.  Any thoughts?  Something similar to when the network connects/disconnects.

Answer (score 28):

Easiest way is to put this in your `MyApplication.onCreate()` method:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.d(TAG, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.d(TAG, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
}, intentFilter);
```

Comment: How and when to unregister the Receiver in this case ?

Comment: You can call [unregisterReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) at any point you like. But assuming you put the above code in `MyApplication.onCreate()`, you don't _have_ to do so because there's no Application.onDestroy() function (the `Application` class is unique that way - see the official docs or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278201/android-ondestroy-or-similar-method-in-application-class) for more info).

Answer (score 12):

The system will broadcast when the screen turns on and off -

In order to listen for these, you can create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for the events:

```
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON
```

They're listed in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF):

Also, there's a [tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) about responding to these events that you might find useful.

Comment: There's a difference between having the same answer and copying one.  We did the same google search is all :P

Comment: Read the doc carefully! This answer actually tells you if the device is "interactive". If the screen is locked, the device is not interactive. Only `android.hardware.display.DisplayManager` can tell you, if the display hardware is currently on. However, that probably requires Android 5.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for Kotlin equivalent code to the top [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19019742/3230821) , this worked for me:

```
val intentFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
registerReceiver(object: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context:Context, intent:Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) {
            Log.d(TAG, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
        }
        else if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {
             Log.d(TAG, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
        }
    }
}, intentFilter)
```

(the auto Kotlin conversion in Android Studio didn't work for me, so I quickly rewrote the snippet - hopefully it saves someone else that extra minute or two)