# Android: onDestroy() or similar method in Application class

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am extending Application class to work with some global variables that need context. I know there is onCreate() method in the Application class that gets called before any other onCreate() in activities, but **I would like to know if there is onDestroy() or similar method in the Application class that could be overridden** so that I would be able to store variables in persistent memory, unregister listener and send last message to server before app process gets killed? If not, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: No, do this in the appropriate methods of `Activity` or `Service`

Comment: Already did that. What a nuisance. Actually, the very reason I'm extending application is because using android service makes me want to cry... or jump off the building :(

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no such call back on a production device for the Application class.

The things you want to do should usually be done right after the changes are made, or in the `onPause()` of the respective app component.

Answer (score 8):

In android, there is no concept of closing an app. The user just leaves: this is the only event that you will be aware of (`onPause()` in an activity). You should design your app so that it fits this lifecycle.

Typically, you should save any changes immediately but asynchronously, so that the UI doesn't hang. This is much better than saving changes in `onPause()` because if something bad happens before the app is paused (the app crashes, the user runs out of battery), all data was already saved properly.

`SharedPreferences` already save changes asynchronously so if you use that, you have nothing else to do. Otherwise you can use Kotlin coroutines or if you use Java, the good old `AsyncTask` is great.

Comment: If you are using whatsapp, then you know they store our last seen.. How can they do this if they can't know when application is closed.

Answer (score 7):

You can override `onDestroy()` in the `Activity` which will be the last one closed in your app and check if it's finishing. In this case your code will not be invoked on a device rotation. But you should be aware that `onDestroy()` is not invoked when an app is closed through device home button.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(isFinishing()){
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all: I'm an absolute beginner

I need to execute some code when my app exits (yes, I know not such thing in Android) and this works  ok for me:

-I have MyApplication wich extends Application. As a member of MyApplication there is an AtomicInteger field named activeActivitiesNumber and a public getter method.

-All the application activities extend MyActivy (which itself extendes Activity)

-MyActivity overrides onCreate, onResume and onStop methods and also have a protected field: 
Protected MyAppication mAppState;

```
a) OnCreate(){
super.onCreate();
mAppState=this.getApplication();...}


b) onResume(){
super.OnResume();
myAppState.getactiveActivitiesNumber().addAndGet(1)
....}

c) onStop(){
super.onStop()

if (myAppStatemyAppState.getactiveActivitiesNumber()..decrementAndGet()<1){
...call exiting code (for instance a public method defined in MyApplication}
}
```

It has a problem: if you start any activity tan doesn´t belong to your application (for instance send an email) it will fire the exiting method.

Another problem (don´t know if it is a real o theoretical one) is that there is no guarantee tan in some situations onStop will be called.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` in the Application class with the following callbacks (I recommend creating an `AppLifecycleCallbacks` class that extends the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`):

```
public interface ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState);
    void onActivityStarted(Activity activity);
    void onActivityResumed(Activity activity);
    void onActivityPaused(Activity activity);
    void onActivityStopped(Activity activity);
    void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState);
    void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible with the `DefaultLifecycleObserver` I put an exemple below

```
public class YourApplication extends Application implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
//Do your onCreate things
}

@Override
public void onStop(@NonNull @NotNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    //Do your onStop things
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(@NonNull @NotNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    //Do your onDestroy things
}
}
```

You can detect onStart onCreate onDestroy onResume onPause onStop this works very well

Comment: Only overriding in Application class doesn't work

Comment: Please read android documentation carefully, the `DefaultLifecycleObserver` only apply for lifecycle owner (which only attach to activities and fragments), and to work properly, the class which implement that protocol should be add into lifecycle-owner by lifecycleOwnerInstance.lifecycle.addObserver method. As a modern developers, should not tricked in code please.

Answer (score 0):

you can access variables in `Application` class from `Activity` and do whatever you want from the Activity's `onDestroy'

Here's an example:

`I have cameraExecutor  in Application`

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    . . .

    // designated executor for camera so UI thread doesn't get blocked
    lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
}
```

`And I'm shutting the cameraExecutor from MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    . . .

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        (this.application as MyApplication).cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }
}
```