# Sending data on user closing the android app

Tags: android

I need to update user information everytime the user after working with the Android App closes the App.How can do the same. do i have some onDestroy kind of method in Application that i can use for the same.
Kindly update.
thanks

Comment: please check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17278496/957654

Comment: Not very helpful .the link does not offer any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There absolutely is such a method - and you guessed it's name correctly. You could override the `onDestroy()` method. 
However, `onDestroy()` is also called with the application is rotated. There are other issues as well.

Android doesn't really have a concept of closing the app. The best way to do this is to save `onPause()` - which will be basically every time the user leaves the app for some reason, such as for multitasking. Just override the `onPause()` method and go from there:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveData()
}

private void saveData() {
    //do whatever to save data here
}
```

I would also read about the [android application lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) to find out more about how all of this works.

Comment: My app has a no of activities .if i write saveData in onPause in one of the activity then as soon as i shift to another activity it will be called which is not desirable.only when the user exits all activities is when i want to saveData

Comment: @user2779311 oh...I see. Then no, there is no way to do this.