# Call method when destroing application

Tags: android

I have a little app and want to save some data when exiting the application. I intended to do this in a method, which I call when the application is exited. I guess I could write in the necessary code in the `onDestroy()` of every possible activity. But is there a more efficient way that I only have to write the code once and it counts for every activity or for the entire application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278201/android-ondestroy-or-similar-method-in-application-class

Comment: what do you mean with "when the application is exited"?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get a callback when your application goes to background. Implement the `onTrimMemory` method in your `Application` class and check for `TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN` level.

```
    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);

        if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
            // your app went to background now. 
        }
    }
```