# How to do something when screen is turning off?

Tags: android

How can I invoke arbitrary code in Android when the screen of the device is turned off? Is there a callback of some sort?

Comment: Turning the screen off doesn't invoke a callback as far as I know but you will always receive `onPause()` and `onStop()` in your activity if you're currently up front... Isn't that enough for your purposes?

Comment: Google about Services in android

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about onPause() and onStop() Thank you very much !

Comment: Will processes that run in the background invoke some callback like the activity?

Comment: Thank you, @mrgenco If you put it as an answer I will mark it for accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system will broadcast a message when the screen turns on and off. Here is the detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208538/1581921

Answer (score 0):

Build a BroadcastReceiver on the on/off screen. The Android system broadcasts a message when certain things happen ( like the screen going on/off , battery changes etc. ) With the BroadCastReceiver you will tell your app how to react when the screen will go off.