# Can't perform action on locking/turning off screen using onPause

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, game-development

I've implemented something similar to [Android notification of screen off/on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208458/android-notification-of-screen-off-on), but it's not working the way it should. All I want to do is stop music when the screen is turned off. I created a screen action class like this

```
public class ScreenAction extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        wasScreenOn = false;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }
}

}
```

Then, in my main activities on create I have this

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenAction();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

In my main activities onPause, I have something like this:

```
 public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (ScreenAction.wasScreenOn) {
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pcmouseclick1);
        mp.setVolume(.1f, .1f);
        mp.start();
        if (buttonState) {
            mServ.reduceVolume();
        }
    }
}
```

I found this from an online source, but I am having issues. It seems that the screen state is always set as true, and I'm not sure how to change this.

How do I utilize this ScreenAction class to turn off music in on Pause ONLY when the user has locked the screen? I feel like I am missing something in the onPause because in onCreate I link to the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // when the screen is about to turn off
    // or when user is switching to another application

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // only when screen turns on
    // or when user returns to application


    super.onResume();
}
```

Here you can see the entire lifecycle of an Activity in android:
[Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: This doesn't answer how to do something "in on Pause ONLY when the user has locked the screen"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could also start and stop your music directly from the receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // Pause music player
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // Resume music player
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `ScreenAction.wasScreenOn` in `onPause`, but that's happening *before* the `BroadcastReceiver` is called to notify you that the screen is being turned off.  So at that point, `ScreenAction.wasScreenOn` is still true, and then it's set to false, but `onPause` has already run, so your music never gets paused.

To solve this, you should take the action directly in response to the screen turning off in the `BroadcastReceiver`.  If you need to interact with your UI, consider a solution like LiveData as an abstraction so that you're not reliant on your Activity being paused at the exact moment the screen is turned off (consider also that the `onPause` solution wouldn't work if your Activity weren't currently visible).